# Exceeded timeout of 300000ms while waiting for Ingress resource kafka-cluster-kafka-bootstrap in namespace kafka to be addressable with istio ingress

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway, strimzi, istio-operator

I use istio-ingress gateway and virtualservice to expose Strimzi kafka zookeeper pod is getting up but not kafka-cluster both kafka bootstrap and kafka broker ingress are comming up

```
$ kubectl get ingress -n kafka
NAME                            CLASS   HOSTS                              ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
kafka-cluster-kafka-0           istio   kafka-broker0.example.com               80, 443   22m
kafka-cluster-kafka-bootstrap   istio   kafka-bootstrap.example.com             80, 443   22m
```

getting below error

```
io.strimzi.operator.common.operator.resource.TimeoutException: Exceeded timeout of 300000ms while waiting for Ingress resource kafka-cluster-kafka-bootstrap in namespace kafka to be addressable
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ingress resource does not have the `address` field filled by the Ingress controller in the `.status` section. That is the indication for Strimzi that this Ingress resource was accepted and should work ... and that is what Strimzi is waiting for.

Please keep in mind that the Ingress support in Strimzi is developed and tested with the [Kubernetes Ingress-NGINX Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx). The various Ingress controllers do not have always the same behavior and are not always 1 for 1 replacements. So while some might work out of the box, others might not and you might need to update the status manually (I know some users did that with some of the controllers) or even manage the Ingress resources yourself.

Comment: Noted @jakub thanks for the feedback, will try that option.

Comment: do you have any link or doc or how do i update address status manually.

Comment: You can use `kubectl edit/status` to edit the status section. But no idea how will it work with your Ingress controller.

Comment: i did the same but added address went off after saving and file close.